# Porque no puedo iniciar sesión con php + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

¿Porque no puedo iniciar sesión?
tengo este código de php este es el login.
al momento de verificar en la base de datos me muestra el ID del usuario, pero no me redirige al ingresar bien los datos.
el problema creo que esta al verificar si la clave es igual a la de la base de datos
if ($usuario_existente && password_verify($contrasenia, $usuario_existente->usuario_contrasenia)) {

```
        $_SESSION['sesionIniciada'] = true;
        header("location:index.php");
    } else {
        $error = "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
    }
```

```
<?php
include_once("conexion.php");
session_start(); // Asegúrate de iniciar la sesión al comienzo del script

if (isset($_POST["usuario"]) && isset($_POST["contrasenia"])) {
    $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
    $contrasenia = $_POST["contrasenia"];
    echo $usuario."</br>";
    echo $contrasenia."</br>";

    if (empty($usuario)) {
        $error = "Por favor, rellena el campo de usuario";
    } else if (empty($contrasenia)) {
        $error = "Por favor, rellena el campo de contraseña";
    } else {
        $conexion = new Conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_registrados WHERE usuario_usuario = ?";
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$usuario]);
        print_r($stmt);
        print_r($conexion);

        $usuario_existente = $stmt->fetch();
        
        if ($usuario_existente && password_verify($contrasenia, $usuario_existente->usuario_contrasenia)) {
        
            $_SESSION['sesionIniciada'] = true;
            header("location:index.php");
        } else {
            $error = "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**y este archivo es el código del registro.php.**

```
<?php include_once("conexion.php");?>
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Verificar si los campos están definidos y no están vacíos
    if (isset($_POST["usuario"]) && isset($_POST["contrasenia"]) && isset($_POST["sub_contrasenia"])) {

        $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
        $contrasenia = $_POST["contrasenia"];
        $sub_contrasenia = $_POST["sub_contrasenia"];

        if (empty($usuario) || empty($contrasenia) || empty($sub_contrasenia)) {
            $error = "Por favor, complete todos los campos";
        } 
        else {
            try{
                if($sub_contrasenia == $contrasenia){
                    // Evitar inyección SQL usando sentencias preparadas
                    $conexion = new Conexion();
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `usuarios_registrados` (`usuario_id`, `usuario_usuario`, `usuario_contrasenia`) VALUES (null, ?, ?)";
                    
                    // Hash de la contraseña (deberías usar un algoritmo de hash seguro)
                    $hash_contrasenia = password_hash($contrasenia, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        
                    // Preparar la consulta
                    $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        
                    // Ejecutar la consulta preparada
                    $stmt->execute([$usuario, $hash_contrasenia]);
        
                    header("location: iniciarSesion.php");
            
                }else{
                    $error = "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
                }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                echo "<script>alert('Hubo un error'.$e)</script>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $error = "Por favor, complete todos los campos";
    }
}

?>
```

Este es el archivo de la conexion.php
aqui lo que hago es que inicializo la base de datos y extraigo los datos.

```
<?php

class Conexion{
    private $servidor = "localhost";
    private $usuario = "root";
    private $contrasenia = "";
    private $conexion;

    public function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->conexion = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->servidor};dbname=sistema_de_usuarios", $this->usuario, 
            $this->contrasenia);
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            throw new Exception("Error en la base de datos". $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function prepare($sql){
        return $this->conexion->prepare($sql, []);
    }

    public function registrarUsuario($sql, $parametros){
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($parametros);
        return $this->conexion->lastInsertId();
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra tu código actualmente? ¿De qué tipo es y qué tamaño tiene la columna donde guardas el password en la base de datos? ¿Usaste `password_hash` al momento de hacer el `INSERT` y/o `UPDATE` del password?

Comment: Ya "debuggeaste" tu código?? En lugar de toda la función pon un `IF` y si entra un mensaje **OK** y sino **ERROR**. Ya con eso determinas si es la DB o redirección.